# i'm getting an error 403 when i send an ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

This is the javascript code

```
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    parent.find('.archiveSpinner').css('display','block');
    var title = $(this).attr('data-title');
    var desc = $(this).attr('data-desc');
    var source = $(this).attr('data-source');
    var datePublished = $(this).attr('data-datePublished'); 
    var _title = parent.find('.title').html();
    var _desc = parent.find('.description').html();
    var _source = parent.find('.source a').attr('source');
    var _datePublished = parent.find('.date').attr('date');
    var serverPage ="archiveThisNow.php?title=" + title + "&desc=" + desc + "&source=" + source + "&_title=" + _title + "&_desc=" + _desc + "&_source=" + _source + "&datePublished=" + datePublished + "&_datePublished=" + _datePublished;
        //the Json Request    

        $.get(serverPage,
                function(data) {
                    if(!data){}
                    else{
                            parent.find('#archiveError').hide();
                            $(data).appendTo(parent);
                            parent.find('.archiveSpinner').css('display','none');
                            setTimeout(function (){ parent.find('#archiveError').fadeOut('slow'); },5000);
                        }
                    });
```

it works perfectly offline but when i upload it to the server online i get this error

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /archiveThisNow.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Please i need help on this ASAP. Thank you

Comment: 403 and 404 aren't javascript errors - they're server errors. Sounds like a problem with your htaccess or file permissions.

Comment: Hmm, what does _You don't have permission to access /archiveThisNow.php on this server._ mean?

Comment: Check the file permissions of `/archiveThisNow.php` are set correctly on the server.

Comment: the permissions on the file is 0644

Answer (score 0):

Does the var `serverPage` have the correct path to the page. Remember it's relative to the html/php file that is calling it, not the javascript file that this might be in.

Comment: If path was not correct server error would be 404. it much likes permission issue, e.g. `deny from all` in .htaccess

Comment: i have no htaccess file on the site directory, i deleted it when the error came up and the path is correct because it works fine on my wamp server

Comment: @Kaspersky 403 is a permission issue.

Comment: the permission on the file is 0644 what do u suggest i do ?